# Testcafe / Jenkins job failing TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, jenkins, testcafe

I have a jenkins job that has worked consistently for the past 2 years running various front end tests, but recently I've gotten a stack trace from the job in jenkins that is continuously failing where I'm unsure what to do to fix it.  The stack trace is listed below from the job:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at promisify (internal/util.js:279:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/workspace/Sandbox_Verify/node_modules/testcafe-safe-storage/lib/file.js:18:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/workspace/Sandbox_Verify/node_modules/testcafe-safe-storage/lib/index.js:30:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/workspace/Sandbox_Verify/node_modules/testcafe/lib/dashboard/config-storage.js:3:33) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am facing the same issue. Looks like there was a latest version of testCafe 1.19.0 version released yesterday after which the issue started. If you change your testcafe version to "testcafe": "1.18.6" or remove the ^ it should work. Or may be need to upgrade the nodejs version being used. Got the below warning

npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for testcafe@1.19.0: wanted: {"node":">=14.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})

Comment: Indeed this did apparently fix it for me and I've never had to roll back testcafe from latest until now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the testcafe global version. I think

you can check the global version by `testcafe --version`

and confirm your project installed version -> you can check your  `package.json` file

If both are mismatch means, this issue could occur. So you should set BOTH version to be same

Ex: `npm i -g testcafe@1.18.6`

In package.json --> `testcafe": "^1.18.6`

in my case, its works perfectly. and also I have used `firefox:headless`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is that you are using an outdated Node.js version.
The [crypto.randomUUID](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-safe-storage/blob/d7b095e12e36f942caa32d3b33ecea710b71cfae/src/file.ts#L74) function doesn't exist in Node.js 10.24.1.
Please update it to 14.x and all will work correctly.